# Strange result when using date and strtotime PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, strtotime

I am working with some date conversions in my project , in the Development environment the code works as expected , but in the Production environment it gives a wired result .

In the database when the date value is `0000-00-00` this thing happens .

Code

```
$db_pricedate  = date('dmy', strtotime($row_country_price["pricedate"]));
```

Result in Dev - `010170`

Result in Prod - `3011-1`

It is really weird , the codes and the databases are identical .

Any suggestions . please help . thanks in advance

Both servers have PHP version 5.3.3

Comment: Do you have access to the php.ini file? This is commonly caused by a difference between timezones in php.ini files.

Comment: if it isnt the timezone difference have you tried using $db_pricedate = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $row_country_price["pricedate"]);

Answer (score 0):

It could be from the local configuration ?

Try to add this before your `date()` : `set_local('LC_TIME', 'en');`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong

You are having **32 bit** system on Dev machine and **64 bit** system on Production server.

The reason you are getting weird result is

```
strtotime("0000-00-00 00:00:00");
```

Returns

```
int(-62170005200) // on 64 bit system
false // on 32 bit system
```

Which makes further operations dissimilar.

**Note** : Only applies to **PHP >= 5.3**, i have not checked PHP 5.2 + 64 bit system (it returns false AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of different timezone in your prod. server & dev server. You can overcome this issue by changing your dev server/mysql server timezone.

To see your mysql server tiemzone try this (assuming you are using mysql )

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone;
```

If got problem in changing mysql server timezone, You may change timezone in script.

If still problem not solved use following

```
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-d-m", "0000-00-00");
 echo $date->format("dmy");
```

It must work in both dev & prod server with same result (tested). Guaranty

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

PHP date() convert 0000-00-00 into 01011970 try this

```
if($row_country_price["pricedate"]!= "0000-00-00"){
   $db_pricedate  = date('dmy', strtotime($row_country_price["pricedate"]));
}else{
   $db_pricedate  = $row_country_price["pricedate"];
}
```